# Search using LIKE in a table

Tags: database-theory

I want to retrieve data of 'Match' and 'Average' columns from the following table if '2'
exists using LIKE.
[image]

I have tried by writing the following  query but it failed.

SELECT * FROM `batsman_profile` 
WHERE (Match LIKE '%2%') AND (Average LIKE '%2%');

Can anyone help me how to retrieve data as I want.

Comment: are Match  and  Average fields defined as `VARCHAR` or `NUMBER` ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to treat these numbers as a `String` you should use function `CONVERT(varchar(10), field_name)` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM batsman_profile 
WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(10), Match) LIKE '%2%') 
       AND 
      (CONVERT(varchar(10), Average) LIKE '%2%');
```